# AWS Redshift Bulk Insert + Encoding definition

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, bulkinsert, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to do a bulk insert into REdshift using the `create table as` syntax while defining data type and encoding at the same time? What's the correct syntax?

EG The following gives a syntax error near 'as':

```
create table my_table (
  a int not null encode runlength,
  b int not null encode runlength
) distkey(a) sortkey (a, b) as (
    select * from other_table
);
```

I can only get it to work by defining column name only (a or b) and that's a huge limitation...

Comment: Are you looking for `COPY`?

Comment: don't think so. COPY is from S3 only, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the DIST and SORT keys in a CREATE TABLE … AS query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY ( my_dist )
SORTKEY ( my_sort )
AS
SELECT *
FROM   old_table
;
```

As per the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html  I don't believe you can alter the compression encoding from the source table using CREATE TABLE AS.

Answer (score 0):

More details on Redshift CTAS is given here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_usage_notes.html . In a nutshell, no where its mentioned that you can define the encoding in the CTAS statement. But you can define Sort Keys and Hash Keys. The default encoding chosesn by this statement is none.

However if you want to do a bulk insert, why don't you do in two steps.

1. Create table new_table with your encoding and sort/hash keys
2. Insert into new_table as select * from old_table